How to format time interval in PostgreSQL from "29 days 02:41:44" to a decimal number of days?
I'm trying to change the format of time_discrep (below) into a fraction of days.
Code:
select time1, time2, (time1-time2) as time_discrep
from main_file
order by time1;

Screenshot of results:

I've tried dividing, etc, but it just formats it like 00:00:32 and things like that.
UPDATE: I found something that works, but I don't know if it's the best way:


Please replace the links to images with formatted inline text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) presents reasons as to why images and links to images are problematic.

Please don't use images, only plain text.

A date minus a date give you the number of days between these two dates:
SELECT CAST((INTERVAL '29 days 02:41:44') + current_date AS date) - current_date;

This also works when you have a much larger number of days, like months or years.

The basic math is days + (hours / 24) + (minutes / (24 * 60)) + (seconds / (24 * 60 * 60)). We can write a little function to do the conversion from an interval to a numeric.
create function interval_numeric_days(i interval) returns numeric
language sql
immutable
returns null on null input
return
  extract(days from $1) +
  (extract(hour from $1) / 24) +
  (extract(minute from $1) / (24 * 60)) +
  (extract(second from $1) / (24 * 60 * 60))

select interval_numeric_days('29 days 02:41:44'::interval);
  interval_numeric_days  
-------------------------
 29.11231481481481481481


select interval_numeric_days('2026-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2024-01-01 12:00:00');
    interval_numeric_days     
------------------------------
 730.500000000000000000000000


This deviates slightly more from the truth because a / costs precision, and this does that 3 times. OP's example seems to use timestamp(0) already, so I'm just nitpicking here.


Get the days from the interval using Extract().
Get the fraction by extracting epoch from just the ::time part to turn hours and minutes to seconds in one move, then divide that by one day.
Combine these using a +.

demo at db<>fiddle
select time1
      ,time2
      ,(extract(days from time1-time2)::numeric
        +extract(epoch from (time1-time2)::time)/86400.)::numeric(7,2)
from main_file
order by time1;




time1
time2
time_discrep




2023-10-17 20:16:08
2023-10-13 23:38:53
3.86


2023-11-23 05:00:09
2023-10-03 13:25:48
50.65


2023-12-28 13:29:29
2023-12-06 19:32:01
21.75


2024-02-26 20:13:06
2024-01-11 14:31:16
46.24


2024-02-28 23:50:45
2023-12-31 19:50:10
59.17


2024-03-29 07:22:11
2024-03-05 22:51:15
23.35



The ::numeric(7,2) cast is just to make it look nice - skip that if you prefer higher precision.
Feels nice to have the code work similar to how you'd perform the operation mentally, but it can all be shortened to a single extract:
extract(epoch from time1-time2)/86400.

Which turns out is pretty much what @Bohemian had suggested already.
If you're generating the interval by taking a difference between timestamps, it comes out justified. If you're working with raw intervals, remember to use justify_interval() before extracting anything but epoch, otherwise:
select extract(days from '5 days 48 hours'::interval);









5



Even though the hours amount to 2 more days, they get ignored. Justifying fixes that:
select extract(days from justify_interval('5 days 48 hours'));









7




Convert to seconds using extract(epoch from ...) then use arithmetic to get days as a decimal by dividing by the number of seconds in a day:
select
  time1,
  time2,
  (extract(epoch from time1) - extract(epoch from time2))/86400 as time_discrep
from main_file
order by time1

